Compare content and properties of 2 xml files
I want to compare 2 text (xml) files for their content and their properties.
There are tools to compare only properties or only text like Beyond Compare. Is there anything to compare both together?
I'm looking for GUI application on windows where it can have 2 comparison sets: one for file properties and one for file content.
For Eg. File properties can show permission differences or Encoding differences etc.

GUI? For what system(s)? How should the comparison look? This heavily lacks info.

@Destroy666 updated the question

Could you also specify what exactly do you mean by "file properties"? Like, literal file properties, such as creation date? Or properties within XML, which could be in random order?

@Destroy666 literal file properties. What's within the xml is I would call them the file contents.
